# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a little problem with my captcha code.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const captcha = await createCaptcha();
    try {
        const msg = await member.send('Vous avez 60 secondes pour resoudre ce captcha !', {
            files: [{
                attachment: `${__dirname}/captchas/${captcha}.png`,
                name: `${captcha}.png`
            }]
        });
        try {
            const filter = m => {
                if (m.author.bot) return;
                if (m.author.id === member.id && m.content === captcha) return true;
                else {
                    m.channel.send('Vous avez mal rentrer le captcha.');
                    return false;
                }
            };
            const response = await msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                max: 1,
                time: 20000,
                errors: ['time']
            });
            if (response) {
                await msg.channel.send("Vous venez de vous vérifier ! Vous avez alors l'accès complet au serveur");
                await member.roles.add('737228969426026635');
                await fs.unlink(`${__dirname}/captchas/${captcha}.png`)
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            await msg.channel.send("Vous n'avez pas résolu le captcha.");
            await member.kick();
            await fs.unlink(`${__dirname}/captchas/${captcha}.png`)
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

And I have this error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined
    at makeCallback (fs.js:152:11)
    at Object.unlink (fs.js:1118:14)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wstep\OneDrive\Bureau\DaliaMC\index.js:88:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK'
}
```

There is a capture from what the bot says

What the bot says => [image: bot_reply]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `unlink` method used to delete your captcha image requires a callback function which will be executed once your file is deleted.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const captcha = await createCaptcha();
    try {
        const msg = await member.send('Vous avez 60 secondes pour resoudre ce captcha !', {
            files: [{
                attachment: `${__dirname}/captchas/${captcha}.png`,
                name: `${captcha}.png`
            }]
        });
        try {
            const filter = m => {
                if (m.author.bot) return;
                if (m.author.id === member.id && m.content === captcha) return true;
                else {
                    m.channel.send('Vous avez mal rentrer le captcha.');
                    return false;
                }
            };
            const response = await msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                max: 1,
                time: 20000,
                errors: ['time']
            });
            if (response) {
                await msg.channel.send("Vous venez de vous vérifier ! Vous avez alors l'accès complet au serveur");
                await member.roles.add('737228969426026635');
                fs.unlinkSync(`${__dirname}/captchas/${captcha}.png`);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            await msg.channel.send("Vous n'avez pas résolu le captcha.");
            await member.kick();
            fs.unlinkSync(`${__dirname}/captchas/${captcha}.png`);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

You can use `unlinkSync` as above so it doesn't require a callback function. You can also use `fs.promises.unlink()` to keep await.